# Configuring Pydev(Eclipse) to Use Sage

Tags: eclipse, pydev, sage

I am trying to utilize the Eclipse IDE environment with SAGE using the Pydev extension.

I am following these steps as outline here at http://groups.google.com/group/sage-support/browse_thread/thread/628b80e6bebcc317

Executing a simple code as

```
import sys 
from sage.all import * 
print ("2")
```

gives me an error with the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Documents/eclipse/python/test2.py", line 2, in <module>
from sage.all import * 
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/sage/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/all.py", line 63, in <module>
from sage.ext.c_lib import _init_csage, sig_on_count
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/Desktop/sage/local/lib/python2.6/site-    packages/sage/ext/c_lib.so, 2): Library not loaded: libcsage.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Desktop/sage/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/ext/c_lib.so
  Reason: image not found
```

As by the instructions, trying to execute eclipse from the terminal window(OSX Lion) by the following

```
$sage -sh 
$eclipse
```

only gives me the following traceback

```
-bash: -sh: command not found
```

Any help would be appreciated, notebook() ide of SAGE works fine but Id like to be able to use the Eclipse IDE environment rather than an online server browser.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds as if you entered the '$'. It is sometimes used to indicate a line of input at the terminal. You should also make sure, that sage and eclipse are in your PATH, or you could use the complete path in both cases

```
~/path/to/sage -sh
~/path/to/eclipse
```